# TSQL Date Overflow Issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am trying to wrap my head around an issue that came up on my team internally. Simple query that is calculating the seconds between dates that are later used in calculations.

The issue / error we are getting is: **"The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart."**

This image shows the query and the records its using for the calculations. The only reason it is working is due to the line at the bottom that is explicitly defining the time ranges.

When I remove the times and leave it only up to the dates, we get the overflow error.

`workingStart` has a data type of `datetime` so the only thing I can think of is comparing a date to a datetime string would cause  the overflow?

[image]

**The error:**

[image]

Anyone have an official answer as to why this error occurs? My only guess is the dataType comparison.

**Update:**
Here is the query for all the data when ignoring the `sla dateDiff`.
[image]

Comment: are you sure `workingend` has a value for every record? maybe you've got one with a `0` value that shows up when you have the date-only filtering.

Comment: @MarcB Added another screenshot of the data when not including the calculation for workingEnd

Comment: datediff returns a signed 32bit int for its result, which means for seconds there's a total allowable range of 68 years. you should run a separate query and see if there's any records that have a >=34 year difference between the dates, without using datediff.

Comment: Yah, certainly looks likely to be a dodgy date somewhere in there—all it'll need is for someone to have typed 2106 instead of 2016. Check with a day-based date diff to look for large differences, or just look at your minimum and maximum values for the dates you're datediffing and see if there's anything suspicious.

Comment: So would the datediff be looking through all of the records regardless of the where clause and doing its calculations on data that may not be in my final result set?

Comment: Looks like there is a 1900-01-01 in my SLA Date field. Although that record is not in my result set I was querying for, I assume the math would have been run on every record prior to the WHERE clause selecting my specifics ? @marcB - Wouldn't the WHERE on this order of execution happen prior to dateDiff?

Comment: Official answer is (MSDN datediff):  For millisecond, the maximum difference between startdate and enddate is 24 days, 20 hours, 31 minutes and 23.647 seconds. For second, the maximum difference is 68 years.

Comment: Thanks @olk - While I understand that date is causing the issue, I assumed that the my WHERE clause would have omitted that and not even used it in the calculation for the datediff

Comment: While the WHERE would be evaluated before the DATEDIFF in what's called "logical" query processing order, that's not necessarily how the optimiser will actually be doing things under the covers. In this case the query optimiser has clearly decided that it's actually faster to evaluate the DATEDIFF first and *then* discard some of those results based on the WHERE. This is quite normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still need your results in Seconds.  Use MINUTES and then size up.

```
 cast(DateDiff(MINUTE,[workingStart],[WorkingEnd) as bigint)*60
```

**To generate an overflow in Seconds**, you would need a date difference greater than 68 years, 1 month, 19 days, 3 hours, 14 minutes and 7 seconds

```
Select DateAdd(SS,2147483647 ,'1900-01-01')   -- 1968-01-20 03:14:07.000
Select DateAdd(SS,2147483648 ,'1900-01-01')   -- Overfow with just 1 more second
```

I suspect there is a bogus date (start or end)

**To Prevent the Error**

```
Declare @YourTable table (StartDate Datetime,EndDate DateTime)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('2016-08-01 10:36:16','2016-09-01 11:15:16'),
('1900-01-01 00:00:00','1968-01-20 04:14:07.000')  -- will cause an error


Select *
       ,Seconds=DateDiff(SS,StartDate,EndDate)
 From  @YourTable
 Where Abs(DateDiff(YY,StartDate,EndDate))<68
```

If you remove the WHERE you will see the error

Comment: Thank you, while I am open to answers I really just want to know the root cause of this issue.

Comment: Thanks, John - Can you confirm that `dateDiff` is happening before my `WHERE` clause is filtering my dataset? A little confused why its using a data that isn't defined in my `WHERE` clause range

Comment: If you press CTRL-L, you'll see the query plan and you'll see that the calc is happening before the filter. SQL Server comes up with a query plan that is the fastest. This may or may not mean that certain steps happen before others. As indexes are created/dropped, and table sizes grow and statistics change the plan may change at any time